# Difference between parallel and sequential Convolutions in Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a Convolutional Neural Networks with tensorflow for classifying text. I already found some implemented models and found especially two implementations:

*[I'm not allowed to post more than 2 Links, I will try to provide the sources in the comments]*

However they seem to differ fundamentally in their architecture. The first model uses the convolutions parallel with the input data whereas the second model uses the convolutions in a sequential way. I visualized the two models with tensorboard:

First the *parallel* convolutions. After the convolutions the results are concated and with one fully connected layer the output is created.

[parallel use of convolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTg4E.png)

The *sequential* convolutions seem to be more straight forward, we use the result form the previous layer as the input for the next layer.

[sequential use of convolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdQrn.png)

So my question is, since both are used to classify text, where lies the difference between these two implementations and which one is more suitable for classifying text?

Comment: Sources for the implementations:
 - http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/
 - https://github.com/scharmchi/char-level-cnn-tf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not necessary 'parallel' vs. 'sequential'. From what i'm seeing is that the 'parallel' implementation is actually just óne convolutional layer, however with *different filter sizes*.

Basically, if you just had a convolutional layer with 93x3 features it would be:

```
input                 convoluted                  pooling         
x * y * 1             x' * y' * 9                 x'' * y'' * 9
```

So basically, each filter undergoes the same pooling and convolutional operation.

But the main difference in your 'sequential' model is that he's using features with *different filter sizes*.

```
input                 convoluted                  pooling          concat (may also flatten
x * y * 1             x1 * y1 * 3                 x1' * y1' * 3    x123' * y123' * 9
                      x2 * y2 * 3                 x2' * y2' * 3
                      x3 * y3 * 3                 x3' * y3' * 3
```

Which then get concatted into óne again. The only difference between this and the 'sequential' model is that he is explicitly showing the different filter sizes - but the number of features is exactly the same.

Your 'parallel' and 'sequential' are both just as parallel: each of the feature maps gets convoluted & pooled individually.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you so much for your explanation, this makes way more sense!